# Term for words that have different pronunciations depending on the part of speech

Tags: pronunciation

Is there a general term for a word that has different pronunciations depending on which part of speech it is taking on in a sentence?

For example, "attribute" here is used as a noun

> She has many good attributes; I think I will ask her out.

.. and here as a verb

> I attribute her good looks to the expensive face lotion she uses.

However, the typical pronunciation is different in either case (the stress is on a different syllable).

Comment: In *this* particular case, the term is [*initial-stress-derived noun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun).

Comment: Related: [suprafix (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suprafix)

Comment: @RegDwigнt Hmm, I guess I made my question too general then.

Comment: @RegDwigнt can you please make your comment into an answer so this question no longer shows up as unanswered. It's annoying to click on apparent zero-answer questions, looking to provide an answer, and then discover it's already been answered in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to FSU, these words are referred to as "Equivocal."

> An equivocal word can be pronounced in two different ways, meaning two different things. This is a concept that is the opposite of a homonym, or perhaps an opposite.

Source: [Equivocal Words](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/fun/wordplay/equivocal_words.html)